# How to use shortcode inside of shortcode in theme

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, shortcode, page-template, variables

I am trying to place a shortcode inside another shortcode within a page template, however the various attempts I've made seem to not do anything.

Here's how my code looks now -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]' .$shortcode2. '[/shortcode]');?>
```

I've also tried these -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]$shortcode2[/shortcode]');?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]{$shortcode2}[/shortcode]');?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function that outputs the shortcode (i.e. the one called by `add_shortcode`) must be correctly written to allow this. It should contain the `do_shortcode` handler within its output. If you paste your shortcode functions code I can check it and provide a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the output of the first do_shortcode inside the second call?

```
$output = do_shortcode('[first_shortcode]Some content[/first_shortcode]');
echo do_shortcode('[second_shortcode]'.$output.'[/second_shortcode]');
```

Comment: Fantastic, do you mind hitting the check mark next to my answer so that others searching in the future can see your question was resolved?  Happy coding.

Comment: This does work, but it shouldn't be necessary. If the shortcode functions are correctly written you can do `echo do_shortcode( '[first][second][third]hello[/third][/second][/first]' )`.

Comment: @SimonBlackbourn I tried putting the shortcode inside the shortcode but it didn't work. I didn't write the shortcode functions so Im not sure what was done right or wrong. Thanks though.